# Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<{ [x: number]: string; ... 38 more .}>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FieldError | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-forms

To increase the reusability, I created a TextInputField function in a separate file and call it in other places, one place I can able to call it without any errors, but in one class I'm getting this compile time error like the below, i don't know the exact reason, why it's compiling in one place not in other,

[image: img]

> The Error Message

```
Type 'Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl<{ [x: number]: string; toString: {}; charAt: {}; charCodeAt: {}; concat: {}; indexOf: {}; lastIndexOf: {}; localeCompare: {}; match: {}; replace: {}; search: {}; slice: {}; ... 38 more ...; [Symbol.iterator]: {}; }>> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FieldError | undefined'.
```

> TextInputField

```
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FieldError, RegisterOptions, UseFormRegister } from "react-hook-form";

interface TextInputFieldProps{
    name:string,
    label:string,
    register:UseFormRegister<any>,
    registerOptions?:RegisterOptions,
    error?:FieldError,
    [x:string]:any,
}

const TextInputField = ({name,label,register,registerOptions,error,...props}:TextInputFieldProps) => {
    return (
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId={name+"-input"} >
            <Form.Label> {label} </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control 
            {...props} 
            {...register(name,registerOptions)}
            isInvalid={!!error}
            />
             <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
               {error?.message}
             </Form.Control.Feedback>

        </Form.Group>
    );
}

export default TextInputField;
```

> The place I'm calling this Function

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { User } from "../models/user";
import { SignUpCredentials } from "../network/notes_api";
import * as NotesApi from "../network/notes_api";
import { Button, Form, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import TextInputField from "./form/TextInputField";
import StyleUtils from "../styles/util.module.css";


interface SignUpModalProps {
    onDismiss: () => void,
    onSignUpSuccessful: (user: User) => void,
}

const SignUpModal = ({ onDismiss, onSignUpSuccessful }: SignUpModalProps) => {

    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isSubmitting } } = useForm<SignUpCredentials>();

    async function onSubmit(credentials: SignUpCredentials) {
        try {
            const newUser = await NotesApi.signup(credentials);
            onSignUpSuccessful(newUser);
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return (
        <Modal show onHide={onDismiss}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton >
                <Modal.Title>Sign Up</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

                    <TextInputField
                        name="username"
                        label="Username"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Username"
                        register={register}
                        registerOptions={{ required: "Required" }}
                        error={errors.username} 
                
                    />

                    <TextInputField
                        name="email"
                        label="Email"
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        register={register}
                        registerOptions={{ required: "Required" }}
                        error={errors.email}
                    />

                    <TextInputField
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        register={register}
                        registerOptions={{ required: "Required" }}
                        error={errors.password}
                    />

                    <Button
                        type="submit"
                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                        className={StyleUtils.width100}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>

                </Form>
            </Modal.Body>

        </Modal>
    );
};

export default SignUpModal;
```

> here, the errors.username,email and password coming from
> `SignUpCredentials`

```
export interface SignUpCredentials{
    username:String,
    email:String,
    password:String,
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to see what the type error may be without seeing where `errors.username` is coming from, but I sometimes like to broaden the scope of my reusable components by not giving a prop a concrete type, instead just a partial that many other types could meet: `error?: { message?: string }`. That makes your component more portable, while enforcing the API that is required.

Comment: I added it to the bottom now, it's coming from SignUpCredentials, Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with `react-hooks-form`, what does `FieldError` look like? Is it just a string? That would make sense as the missing methods in the type error look like string prototype fns. Does changing your SignUpCredentials interface to just `string` help? That is set to the `String` class which is different.